# Не подключаются шрифты в IE

Tags: internet-explorer, шрифты

Stack Overflow облазил вдоль и поперек. Одни и те же советы, которые не работают.
Вот мой код - он не работает

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNovaCond-Regular';
  src: url('ProximaNovaCond-Regular.eot');
  src: url('ProximaNovaCond-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('ProximaNovaCond-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('ProximaNovaCond-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'ProximaNovaCond-Semibold';
   src: url('ProximaNovaCond-Semibold.eot');
   src: url('ProximaNovaCond-Semibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('ProximaNovaCond-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('ProximaNovaCond-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'ProximaNovaCond-Bold';
   src: url('ProximaNovaCond-Bold.eot');
   src: url('ProximaNovaCond-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('ProximaNovaCond-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('ProximaNovaCond-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

Comment: код работает - пути прописаны неверно. Пошел отдыхать...

Answer (score 0):

Работающий пример с IE:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Neuron-Heavy";
    src: url("fonts/Neuron/Neuron Heavy.otf") format("opentype");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Поставьте otf, opentype и IE вас поймет.